# Cannot delete directory with .. in name windows 10

Tags: windows-10

Background:  I was using webpack (A javascript application) and missed a / in the config next to the directory.  So it created a directory called "client.."
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTrgz.png)

I've tried everything I can think of to delete the file, and nothing has worked.  I even tried to remove it pragmatically via Java.

Does anyone know a way I can delete this file?

Not that based on the screenshot you will notice that normal methods of deleting hard to remove files did not work.  So this is somehow different than similar questions.

It was answered with using rimraf I was able to delete the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fight fire with fire. Use NodeJS-based tool `rimraf`.

First install it:

```
npm install -g rimraf
```

Then delete the folder:

```
rimraf client..
```